# AppEngine Resume All Tasks

Tags: google-app-engine, queue, task

On my production server, I've got about 500 tasks queues that failed for 30 consecutive times and are waiting in the task queue. Other than manually clicking "Run" for all of them, is there a way to resume all the tasks? I can't anything in the Task Queue docs that points to "resume all" functions.

i tried uploading a new queue.yaml with task_retry_limit: 100 but it doesn't work. It's like, after the 30 mark is hit, appengine just stops executing the tasks

queue.yaml before the failed 500 tasks

```
   queue:
      - name: default
      - rate: 1/s
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that as your tasks continue to fail and retry, the Task Queue system schedules the task to execute further and further into the future.  By default, the maximum ETA is 1 hour.  Was it just the case that your tasks all had an ETA of 1 hour into the future?

Comment: I just had this same problem -- I would pile on some tasks, but I only had one instance of the backend. So, a bunch of them would get `503`'d, and their wait time would double. And that would happen over and over. I saw the ETA time double, like you mentioned. I added `max_backoff_seconds` a la https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/queue and just waited...

Answer (score 0):

Just try it once for new queue name(as refers below) instead of on default queue, This queue is working for me.

```
- name: sales-queue
  rate: 10/s
  max_concurrent_requests: 1
  retry_parameters:
   task_retry_limit: 500
   min_backoff_seconds: 10
   max_backoff_seconds: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no button in the dashboard to run all tasks. The reason for tasks not executing is that 15,000 failed tasks (without succeeded tasks in between, presumably) caused App Engine to dramatically halt task execution regardless of specified task rate.

To resume all tasks, just manually run a few of them. If they succeed, App Engine notices and slowly increases task execution rate again, which causes more tasks to run and succeed, which causes App Engine to increase task rate, and so forth, until default task rate is restored. This will cascade relatively quickly into all 500 tasks being run.